# .Net Delegate not working

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong why delegate is not working in my code?
I have console application which is showing a form at the beginning and use delegate to update the label in the form.

```
namespace DELEGATESAMPLEPROJECT
{
    public class Program
{
    public delegate void OnConfirmCall();
    public OnConfirmCall confirmCall;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1(new Program().getReference()));

        new Program().startFunctionCall();
    }

    public Program getReference(){
        return this;
    }

    public void startFunctionCall(){
        Console.WriteLine("Function Call Started!");
        if(confirmCall != null){
            Console.WriteLine("Function Call Executing...");
            confirmCall();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**FORM1**

```
namespace DELEGATESAMPLEPROJECT
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1(Program thisProgramClass)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            thisProgramClass.confirmCall += saySomething;
        }

        public void saySomething()
        {
            Label1.Text = "Hello World!";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Hi C#!";
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see I am trying to change `"Hi C#!"` into `"Hello World!"` but its not working, What I am missing?

Comment: Because you're using two completely different `Program` instances. Here `Application.Run(new Form1(new Program().getReference())); ` and `new Program().startFunctionCall();` here.

Comment: @ChristophKn please post it as an answer

Comment: @ ChristophKn - Should I rename the Program class?

Comment: @ChristophKn - I don't get it, What changes do I need? I have to call this `new Program().getReference()` to pass the ref. of Program class then call this `new Program().startFunctionCall();` to call non-static method.

Comment: @bernzkie, I posted a answer explaining a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're using two instances of your `Program` class. I see what you're trying to do, but instantiating two forms make them dumb to each other. Thsy don't know each other, so your `confirmCall` delegate will be null.

Fixing this is easy.

Since OP want's to assign the instance to a global field. We're declaring it like this. Also, notice that we've removed the `GetReference` Method at our `Program` this should not be needed.

```
private static Program programInstance = new Program();
```

By doing this, you'll get one instance of your `Program` class and it can be used in your form class by passing this to your `Form1`.

```
Form1 form = new Form1(programInstance);
Application.Run(form);
```

This way, you only have one instance. But IMO you can use the SingleTon pattern in this case, if you really need just one instance.

As a reference to the singleton I suggest to look into Jon Skeet Blog about the [Singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

Comment: I got this error: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.programInstance'`

Comment: @bernzkie, what exactly are you trying to do with the `Program.programInstance`. You should insert the code snippets inside your  `Main` Method inside your `Program` class.

Comment: I am trying to declare `programInstance` as Global so I can use  later. :-/

Comment: f***, I forget this `programRef.startFunctionCall();`, LOL, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace DELEGATESAMPLEPROJECT
{
  public class Program
  {
    public delegate void OnConfirmCall();
    public OnConfirmCall confirmCall;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var programRef = new Program().getReference(); // <- only one reference.

        Application.Run(new Form1(programRef)); //Start the form1

        programRef.startFunctionCall();//Call this function to change the Label in Form1
    }

    public Program getReference(){
        return this;
    }

    public void startFunctionCall(){
        Console.WriteLine("Function Call Started!"); //Write this to confirm the function is called
        if(confirmCall != null){
            Console.WriteLine("Function Call Executing...");//Write this to confirm that the delegate is working
            confirmCall();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `getReference` method is not required at all, is it?

Comment: It is indeed not required. But I wanted it to match with your own code as much as possible to prevent confusion.